# best approach to save bidimensional array values of inputboxes in txt file

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have several inputboxes, and I would like to store all those values in bidimensional array, then write all to a txt file, this is because I want to know the i,j, of the value. So if I make some changes I will only take a look at this array, so how can I insert an array in txt file?

I was doing

```
Dim mArray(100,100) As String

mArray(0,0) = Textbox1.Text
mArray(0,1) = Textbox2.Text
...



Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\file.txt", False)
objWriter.WriteLine(mArray)
objWriter.Close()
```

or would it be better to do:

```
Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\file.txt", False)
objWriter.WriteLine(Textbox1.Text)
objWriter.WriteLine(Textbox2.Text)
objWriter.WriteLine(Textbox3.Text)
objWriter.WriteLine(Textbox4.Text)
...
objWriter.WriteLine(Textboxn.Text)

objWriter.Close()
```

Comment: What about some serialization e.g. JSON or xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know for two dimensional arrays but for a single dimensional array here is the code :

```
Dim mArray(100) as string
mArray(0) = TextBox1.Text
.
.
.
.

For I as integer = 0 to mArray.count - 1
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\file.txt", False)
    objWriter.WriteLine(mArray(I))
    objWriter.Close()
Next I
```

I think for two dimensional array you need to use nested for like

```
For I as integer = 0 to ...........
    For J as integer = 0 to ..........
        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\file.txt", False)
        objWriter.WriteLine(mArray(I,J))
        objWriter.Close()
    Next J
next I
```